# Share Button is taking only recent post title and excerpts in all the shares button

Tags: php, html, wordpress, share

I have encounter another problem right now that all my share button in the post is getting the recent post that i had posted title and excerpts. I needed each post share with its title and excerpts. I am using Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags for WordPress plugins to set the image and meta tags but it worked only for image. 
My website is http://shareeveryone.com/questions

I had set the meta tag as below:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<meta name="og:description" content="<?php the_excerpt(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Look into the source code of one of your post pages, http://shareeveryone.com/question/kuck/ – and you will see that both meta tags have `content=""`. `the_title` does only return the title, so you’re missing an `echo` to actually output the value. `the_excerpt` should generate output directly – but not sure whether you are using it in the correct place, because according to docs it _“must be used within `The_Loop`”_

Comment: I was just testing the share button want wanted to get a title and description of the respective post to the share page. Is it can be done ?@CBroe